# Adjacent sibling selectors + select element which comes first

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I want to apply red color only to class t2 which are followed by t3.

For example

```
<div class="t1">
  <div class="t2">2</div>
  <div class="t3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="t1">
  <div class="t3">3</div>
  <div class="t2">2</div>
  <div class="t4">4</div>
</div>
<div class="t1">
  <div class="t2">2</div>
</div>
```

I want to apply red color only to class t2 which are followed by t3 in class t1.

t2 + t3 -> selects t3 and applies css to t3
t2 ~ t3 also does the same.

what other options do I have. Order of t2 is not know as it might be first/last/any child of t1.

Comment: Read [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) (might even be a duplicate of that).

Comment: @Xufox - seems like a dup to me.